# ANTLR rule to skip method body

Tags: c#, antlr, rule, skip

My task is to create ANTLR grammar, to analyse C# source code files and generate class hierarchy. Then, I will use it to generate class diagram.

I wrote rules to parse namespaces, class declarations and method declarations. Now I have problem with skipping methods bodies. I don't need to parse them, because bodies are useless in my task.

I wrote simple rule:

```
body:
'{' .* '}'
;
```

but it does not work properly, when method looks like:

```
void foo()
{
  ...
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

rule matches first brace what is ok, then it matches

```
... 
{
  ...
```

as 'any'(.*) and then third brace as final brace, what is not ok, and rule ends.

Anybody could help me to write proper rule for method bodies? As I said before, I don't want to parse them - only to skip.

**UPDATE:**

here is solution of my problem strongly based on Adam12 answer

```
body:
'{' ( ~('{' | '}') | body)* '}'
;
```

Comment: You are in for a very difficult task  You will have to accept pairs of { and } within the  body, and you will also have to ignore comments and string-content inside the body.  strings like "[{" is very common when generating small portions of json or /* if (...) { something*/ for some code that is temporary removed and they will disturb your rules.

Comment: @Casperah, could you give me some example how accept pairs of { } ? I think that I should use recursion here, but nothing more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use recursive rules that match parentheses pairs.

```
rule1 : '(' 
  (
    nestedParan
  | (~')')*
  )
  ')';

nestedParan : '('
  (
    nestedParan
  | (~')')*
  )
  ')';
```

This code assumes you are using the parser here so strings and comments are already excluded. ANTLR doesn't allow negation of multiple alternatives in parser rules so the code above relies on the fact that alternatives are tried in order. It should give a warning that alternatives 1 and 2 both match '(' and thus choose the first alternative, which is what we want.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the recursion of (nested) blocks in your lexer. The trick is to let your class definition also include the opening `{` so that not the entire contents of the class is gobbled up by this recursive lexer rule.

A quick demo that is without a doubt not complete, but is a decent start to "fuzzy parse/lex" a Java (or C# with some slight modifications) source file:

```
grammar T;

parse
 : (t=. {System.out.printf("\%-15s '\%s'\n", tokenNames[$t.type], $t.text.replace("\n", "\\n"));})* EOF
 ;

Skip
 : (StringLiteral | CharLiteral | Comment) {skip();}
 ;

PackageDecl
 : 'package' Spaces Ids {setText($Ids.text);}
 ;

ClassDecl
 : 'class' Spaces Id Spaces? '{' {setText($Id.text);}
 ;

Method
 : Id Spaces? ('(' {setText($Id.text);}
              | /* no method after all! */ {skip();}
              )
 ;

MethodOrStaticBlock
 : Block {skip();}
 ;

Any
 : . {skip();}
 ;

// fragments
fragment Spaces 
 : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+
 ;

fragment Ids
 : Id ('.' Id)*
 ;

fragment Id 
 : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '0'..'9')*
 ;

fragment Block
 : '{' ( ~('{' | '}' | '"' | '\'' | '/')
       | {input.LA(2) != '/'}?=> '/'
       | StringLiteral
       | CharLiteral
       | Comment
       | Block
       )*
   '}'
 ;

fragment Comment
 : '/*' .* '*/'
 | '//' ~('\r' | '\n')*
 ;

fragment CharLiteral
 : '\'' ('\\\'' | ~('\\' | '\'' | '\r' | '\n'))+ '\''
 ;

fragment StringLiteral
 : '"' ('\\"' | ~('\\' | '"' | '\r' | '\n'))* '"'
 ;
```

I ran the generated parser against the following Java source file:

```
/*
    ... package NO.PACKAGE; ...
*/
package foo.bar;

public final class Mu {

  static String x;

  static {
    x = "class NotAClass!";
  }

  void m1() {
    // {
    while(true) {
      double a = 2.0 / 2;
      if(a == 1.0) { break; } // }
      /* } */
    }
  }

  static class Inner {
    int m2   () {return 42; /*comment}*/ }
  }
}
```

which produced the following output:

```
PackageDecl     'foo.bar'
ClassDecl       'Mu'
Method          'm1'
ClassDecl       'Inner'
Method          'm2'
```